# Global error page in JBoss7

Tags: java, http, servlets, error-handling, jboss7.x

I just want to override the HTTP 404 error page in Jboss7.

I have tried ,

```
<error-page>  
       <error-code>404</error-code>  
       <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

But, until unless my application got up, I cannot see the page for 404 status code.

I need to have to have an error page while jboss got up and deploying my application, mean time if anybody tries to access my application , need to show them customize error page.

Could anybody help me out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize JBoss AS7 404 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476028/how-to-customize-jboss-as7-404-page)

Comment: @FedericoSierra : No it is not. As the link was telling about creating an error war and process the error pages. Here I want to override Global error page for Jboss. It should not be .war level , it should be jboss level.