# Spring MVC: how to handle incoming request to wrong context path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How do we handle incoming request to a wrong contextpath in spring mvc?

I have deployed a spring mvc application having contextpath as

http://exampledomain.com/mycontext

But when I try accessing url http://exampledomain.com/wrongcontext I get error as HTTP Status 404 - /wrongcontext/

I have implemented error handling which works fine for all wrong url when correct context path is used but it does not work for wrong context path.

I am trying to understand how do we redirect all incoming request to specific page in production environment..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your application can only see requests to its context `/mycontext` There is nothing your application can do about requests to other contexts.

You can however deploy an application at the root context `/` and implement an error handler there.

Check out this answer: [How to customize JBoss AS7 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476028/how-to-customize-jboss-as7-404-page)

That answer relates to JBoss, but the same idea will apply on other servers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to handle wrong context path requests in Spring since it only will handle the requests which goes to your context root. You have to take a look at server configuration parameters to redirect those kind of requests. If you are working on Tomcat, check **path** parameter of context.xml:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Answer (score -1):

We can use `@ExceptionHandler` inside a `@Controller` or  `@ControllerAdvice` to handle such kind of exceptions and decide on the view page to be rendered.

```
@ExceptionHandler({ HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
        HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class, HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class,
        MissingPathVariableException.class, MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
        ServletRequestBindingException.class,MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, MissingServletRequestPartException.class, 
        NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    public ModelAndView handleException(){
        return new ModelAndView("errorpage");
    }
```